# In mvn, how do I pass the object store key command?

Tags: maven, mule4, anypoint-platform, persistent-object-store, anypoint-rtf

How can we pass the persistent object store 'true' value through mvn command to get the trick mark in runtime manager for RTF applications? As of now, we are not passing objectstore through the pom file, but we need to do so through Jenkins script.

CMD: mvn deploy –DmuleDeploy -DobjectStore = true

Will this cmd -DobjectStore = true work or are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mule Maven Plugin for Mule 4 in the `<deployementSetting>` [section](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/2.0/deploy-maven-4.x#deployment-settings) add the element `<persistentObjectStore>`. Its value will be the property that you are defining in the command line. For example:

```xml
  <persistentObjectStore>${objectStore}</persistentObjectStore>
```

Then you can define the property value in the command line to set it to true or false: `mvn deploy -DobjectStore=true ...`

Comment: Thanks@aled, can we inject this key-value "-DobjectStore = true" in runtime manager properties directly with out defining key in pom xml file.

Comment: Do you mean manually in the UI?

Comment: Through Jenkins CD pipeline by using the mvn command "mvn deploy –DmuleDeploy -DobjectStore = true". My ask is it's mandatory to keep this key-value ' <persistentObjectStore>${objectStore}</persistentObjectStore>' in pom file or we can directly call from mvn command.

Comment: In the command line you are only defining the value of a Maven property that does nothing. You have to define the configuration in the pom if you want to set the persistantObjectStore configuration. The property is only used to set the value dynamically instead of a constant true or false. You could call it abc like `-Dabc=true` if it makes the example more clear. Unless you use the value in the pom it doesn't activate anything by itself. That's how Maven works.

Comment: Thanks@aled for your inputs. Actually we have one requirement to add multiple key-value pair in cloudhub properties section. For this stuff we need to do it in Jenkins CD pipeline. During rutime, we need to add/override multiple xml properties tags in pom file properties section. after that, we need to call a mvn deploy command. It is possible?

Comment: That is a different question. If an answer to your original question is valid you should accept/upvote it. Then you should ask additional questions separately, each in its own question.

Comment: Of course before asking search previous questions because there are good chances this has already been asked.

Comment: Actually, that other question seems to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645233/721855