# In Runtime manager, Mule application should be add multiple properties(key-value)

Tags: java, cloud, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

In Runtime Manager CloudHub properties we need to add more than 100 properties. Currently we add the properties manually, apply the changes and the application is redeployed instead of adding them manually. Shall we pass these property values through the mule pom xml file using the below property section

```
      <properties>
        <key>value</key>
      </properties>
```

It is possible to create a file and read the properties and then pass the key as a property in pom xml file.

Please suggest a valid scenario how we can add more than 100 properties in runtime manager by mule code or ci/cd process or java.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `<properties>` element inside the `<cloudHubDeployment>` element of the Mule Maven Plugin then yes. Using Maven to deploy applications with the Mule Maven Plugin you can configure the properties there. It is a common method to implement CI/CD pipelines. The name `key` is not literal. You need to replace it by the name of the property.

Example:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
  <configuration>
    <cloudHubDeployment>
      ...
      <properties>
        <host>myserver.mycompnany.com</host>
        <environment>test</environment>
      </properties>
    </cloudHubDeployment>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Do not confuse with Maven properties section or command line properties that are only used internally during Maven execution.

If you don't want to use Maven other alternatives are to use any language/scripts to use [CloudHub 1.0 REST API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub-1/cloudhub-api) or use the [Anypoint CLI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-cli/4.x/) command line tool.